# How to iterate through nodes in scrapy using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a website and the content of the html looks something like this

```
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading727654">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse727654" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse727654">
                    <div class="product-name">
                        <span class="product-title">
                            Aubrey<br><i>AGE DEFYING THERAPY CLEANSER 3.4 OZ</i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-price">
                        <span>
                            $10.99 / 3.40 OZ 
                        </span>
                </a>
            </h4>
</div>
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading727655">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse727655" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse727654">
                    <div class="product-name">
                        <span class="product-title">
                            Aubrey<br><i>AGE DEFYING THERAPY LIQUID</i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-price">
                        <span>
                            $12.99 / 4.40 OZ 
                        </span>
                </a>
            </h4>
</div>
```

My python code snippet to extract this is something like

```
def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2] + '.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            for node in response.xpath('//div[re:test(@class, "panel-heading")]'):
                print node.xpath('//span[re:test(@class, "product-title")]//text()').extract()
                print node.xpath('//span[re:test(@class, "product-price")]//text()').extract()
```

When I run the above scrapy code in Python, I am not getting the expected output, the same content is being repeated 100 times. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: It would be easier if you give us the url you are trying to scrape so we can make a test. Is that possible?

Comment: Yeah sure. https://www.naturalgrocers.com/products/departments/body-care/?mg=1&product_name=&product_sort_by=title_asc&store_location_id=U089&department-product-search=&department_link=BODY+CARE

Comment: @goutam which values from the HTML are you looking for ?

Comment: I am looking for the product title and product price

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to *prepend dots* to your inner XPath expressions to make them work in the context of `node`. Otherwise the search starts from the root of the tree:

```
def parse(self, response):
    filename = response.url.split("/")[-2] + '.html'
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        for node in response.xpath('//div[re:test(@class, "panel-heading")]'):
            print node.xpath('.//span[re:test(@class, "product-title")]//text()').extract()
            print node.xpath('.//span[re:test(@class, "product-price")]//text()').extract()
```